# Trouble compiling helloworld.cu

Tags: cuda

While compiling this hello world sample in Ubuntu 10.10

This is from [CUDA by Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131387685), chapter 3 (No compile instructions provided >:@)

```
#include <iostream>

__global__ void kernel (void){


}

int main(void){

    kernel <<<1,1>>>();
        printf("Hellow World!\n");
    return 0;

}
```

I got this:

> $ nvcc -lcudart hello.cu hello.cu(11): error: identifier "printf" is
>   undefined
>
> 1 error detected in the compilation of
>   "/tmp/tmpxft_00007812_00000000-4_hello.cpp1.ii".

Why? How should this code be compiled?

Comment: @awoodland: Hmmmm, the second answer says it does, and indeed section B14 has "printf(“Hello thread %d, f=%f\n”, threadIdx.x, f);"

Comment: how is this supposed to be compiled then?

Comment: the code stuff from that book are mere snippets if I recall correctly, and not always full examples. Not to mention they use alto of bad practise in those example....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to include `stdio.h` or `cstdio`not `iostream` (which is for `std::cout` stuff) for `printf` (see `man 3 printf`). I found the source code for the book [here](https://github.com/jiekebo/CUDA-By-Example/blob/master/common/book.h).

`chapter03/hello_world.cu` is actually:

```
/*
 * Copyright 1993-2010 NVIDIA Corporation.  All rights reserved.
 *
 * NVIDIA Corporation and its licensors retain all intellectual property and 
 * proprietary rights in and to this software and related documentation. 
 * Any use, reproduction, disclosure, or distribution of this software 
 * and related documentation without an express license agreement from
 * NVIDIA Corporation is strictly prohibited.
 *
 * Please refer to the applicable NVIDIA end user license agreement (EULA) 
 * associated with this source code for terms and conditions that govern 
 * your use of this NVIDIA software.
 * 
 */


#include "../common/book.h"

int main( void ) {
    printf( "Hello, World!\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

Where `../common/book.h` includes `stdio.h`.

The `README.txt` file details how to compile the examples:

```
The vast majority of these code examples can be compiled quite easily by using 
NVIDIA's CUDA compiler driver, nvcc. To compile a typical example, say 
"example.cu," you will simply need to execute:

> nvcc example.cu
```

Comment: I posted the second sample from the chapter verbatim, Section 3.2.2, and it does include <iostream>

Comment: @omgzor: That's a mistake. Check the [errata](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-example-errata-page-0) for the book (from the page I linked to in my answer). ''p.23,25 - The #includes for this example are incorrectly shown as: #include <iostream> and #include "book.h." This has been corrected in the downloadable code package, but should read: #include <stdio.h> and #include "../common/book.h"''. (Also you're probably looking at the code for `chapter03/simple_kernel.cu` rather than `chapter03/hello_world.cu`)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't check the code for the book, as the pdf I have doesn't mention it as available.

Comment: The link provided in the answer is now broken. Here is an alternative link https://github.com/jiekebo/CUDA-By-Example/blob/master/common/book.h perhaps it might be useful   to someone.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that the compiler does not know where to find `printf` function. It
needs to know where to find it. The `include` directive is used to tell the compiler where to find it.

```cpp
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void) {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

After the fix, it would work:

```sh
$ nvcc hello_world.cu
$ ls
a.out  hello_world.cu
$ a.out
Hello World!
```